Explaining two definitions: $V$ is defined over $k$ and the field of definition of $V$

Definition: Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-variety. Then $V=V(I)$ for some ideal $I\subset \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. If $I$ admits a generating set in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ for some field $k\subset \mathbb{C}$, we say that $V$ is defined over $k$. We then have that $V=W_{\mathbb{C}}$ for the $k$-variety $W$ defined by the ideal $J=I\cap k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. The smallest field such that this holds is called the field of definition of $V$.

$(1)$: What does generating set mean here? Does that mean $I=(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ for some polynomials in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ such that $I=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$? (i.e. $I$ contains all the basis elements of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$) But if this is correct, then $J=I\cap k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]=I=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. I must have misunderstood the concept。
$(2)$: Could you provide some simple examples? I am a sophomore and I am working on a project. The lecture note just provides the definition, which confused me. So, I want a concrete example, thank you very much.

Who gave you this definition? It doesn't agree with other definitions that I believe are more standard, and also it is not at all clear as written that there exists a smallest field of definition.

@QiaochuYuan This is from mila's doctoral thesis called "The trace field of hyperbolic gluings". There is a remark: The existence of a minimal field of definition (for affine varieties) was first proven by Weil.

It's not true that $I \cap k[x_1,\dots,x_n] = I$ in general. Take $k=\mathbb{Q}$, $n=1$, and $I=(f_1)=(x)$. Then the ideal $I$ contains e.g. $\sqrt{2}x$ which is not in $I \cap \mathbb{Q}[x]$.

I think the definition is not hard to follow. All you need is an example.
Example: Consider the $\mathbb C$-variety $X=V(ix^2+iy^2-i)$, where $ix^2+iy^2-i\in \mathbb C[x,y]$. Clearly, the ideal $(ix^2+iy^2-i)$ admits another generator $x^2+y^2-1$ such that $X=V(ix^2+iy^2-i)=V(x^2+y^2-1)$. Then, $x^2+y^2-1$ can be considered in $\mathbb R[x,y]$ or $\mathbb Q[x,y]$. By the definition, we can say that $X$ is defined over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb Q$. In this case, $\mathbb Q$ is the smallest field, so it is the field of definition of $X$. On the other hand, we find a $\mathbb Q$-variety $Y=V(x^2+y^2-1)$ where $x^2+y^2-1\in \mathbb Q[x,y]$ such that its complexification $Y_{\mathbb C}=X$, since $(ix^2+iy^2-i)\cap \mathbb Q[x,y]=(x^2+y^2-1)$.
